# how to get fixed header and scrolling list item on nativescirpt radlistview

Tags: android, nativescript

> my sample code here. the problem is when i scroll the list header will
>   go off, which should be fixed in position. as per my requirement.

```
        <lv:RadListView.headerItemTemplate>
            <GridLayout rows="auto" columns="*,*,*,*" borderWidth=".01" borderColor="#004C97" padding='5' class="bg fc4" fontWeight="bold">
                <Label text="Date" fontSize="12" col='0' fontWeight="bold" textAlignment="left" />
                <Label text="Category" col='1' fontSize="12" fontWeight="bold" verticalAlignment="center" textAlignment="left" />
                <Label text="Amount" fontSize="12" col='3' fontWeight="bold" textAlignment="right" />
                <Label text="Comments" col="2" fontSize="12" fontWeight="bold" verticalAlignment="center" textAlignment="left" />
            </GridLayout>
        </lv:RadListView.headerItemTemplate>

        <lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
            <GridLayout rows="auto" columns="*,*,*,*" borderWidth=".01" borderColor="#004C97" padding='10' class="fc4" fontWeight="bold">
                <Label text="{{date}}" fontSize="14" col='0' fontWeight="bold" textAlignment="left" />
                <Label text="{{expenseCat}}" col='1' fontSize="14" fontWeight="bold" verticalAlignment="center" textAlignment="left" />
                <Label text="{{expenseAmount}}" fontSize="14" col='3' fontWeight="bold" textAlignment="right" />
                <Label text="{{comments}}" col="2" fontSize="14" fontWeight="bold" verticalAlignment="center" textAlignment="left" />
            </GridLayout>
        </lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>

    </lv:RadListView>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a GridLayout with `rows="auto,*"`. Place your header layout (0th row) above ListView (1st row) so it stays fixed.